# Objects and graphing in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, physics

I am a novice at programming. The program I plan to create will be used for college physics research.
So my problem is more than just a code one. To keep it simple: I'm working on a research project which involves creating 3d Unit cells (let's call them rectangles for now) and placing points at random vertices of these rectangles. The rectangles are supposed to be adjacent with each other. The random points will be then used for different calculations. I was wondering if this is possible using matplotlib. Can I create an array of cubes/rectangular prisms and place random points on their vertices? Also, is Matplotlib the best way to do this? Do you recommend I approach this another way?

Comment: yes you can, matplotlib should work perfectly well.

Comment: matplotlib is good for displaying your data, but it won't store your data or do calculations on it. Your main challenge will be creating a suitable data structure to represent the elements of your model, and then writing code to do calculations on them. To store the data, you could consider numpy arrays, pandas dataframes or possibly lists of tuples (native data types). E.g. You could create a matrix with one row for each point and one column for each coordinate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly do something like this with Python and Matplotlib. Check out this code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# Generate a 3D grid
ext = np.arange(0,10,1)
xx, yy, zz = np.meshgrid(ext,ext,ext)
values = np.zeros((10,10,10))

# Put some values on a few vertices
xInd = np.random.randint(0,10,20)
yInd = np.random.randint(0,10,20)
zInd = np.random.randint(0,10,20)

values[[xInd,yInd,zInd]] = np.random.random(20)

# Create a scatter plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
im = ax.scatter(xx,yy,zz,c=values, cmap=plt.cm.spectral_r, edgecolor=None, alpha=0.7)
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_xlabel('y')
ax.set_xlabel('z')
plt.colorbar(im)
fig.show()
```

Which generates the figure below:

[image]

If you need to use unit rectangles (i.e. with actual width/height/depth) then you would need a slightly more complicated data structure but the same ideas would work.

Comment: Thanks. This seems like something that would fit well.